Not able to restream RTMP with OvenMediaEngine
Is anyone who has experience with a restream RTMP from OvenMediaEngine to external clients.
Snip of the configuration part
<Applications>
<Application>
<Name>live</Name>
<Type>live</Type>

<Publishers>
<AppWorkerCount>2</AppWorkerCount>
<StreamWorkerCount>4</StreamWorkerCount>
<WebRTC>
...
</WebRTC>
<RTMPPush></RTMPPush>
</Publishers>

<OutputProfiles>
...
</OutputProfiles>

<Providers>
<SRT />
<WebRTC>
..
</WebRTC>
<RTMP>
<BlockDuplicateStreamName>true</BlockDuplicateStreamName>
</RTMP>
<MPEGTS>
...
</MPEGTS>
</Providers>
...
</Application>
...
</Applications>

I can't view stream with VLC client like
rtmp://ome.ip.address:1935/applicationName/streamName
I can view this stream with
ws://ome.ip.address:3333/applicationName/streamName in the web player over WebRTC.
I read this doc
https://airensoft.gitbook.io/ovenmediaengine/push-publishing
and in my logs I saw "unknown key publishers...push"
Looks like it is mistake in the doc or I did something wrong?
In general configuration works as expected just not able to view with external client published streams with RTMP.
Current scheme is:
outside client send RTMP to OME. From OME over web-player can view stream using WebRTC
